# Using regex how to exclude a mail domain and its subdomains?

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript I'm trying exclude a specific mail domain and all its subdomains using regex. If the domain I want to exclude is spammail.com. I need to exclude all the following

```
name@spammail.com
name@xx.spammail.com
name@xxx.spammail.com
...
```

Comment: this should work for the regex part https://regex101.com/r/TwC4ma/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
let checkValid = (mail) => !/([^\@]*\@)(([^\.]*\.{1})*)(spammail\.com)/.test(mail);

console.log(checkValid("name@spammail.com")) //false
console.log(checkValid("name@xx.spammail.com")) //false
console.log(checkValid("name@xxx.spammail.com")) //false
console.log(checkValid("name@notspammail.com")) //true
console.log(checkValid("name@xxxspammail.com")) //true
```

Comment: Thanks .. but infact this accepts the spammail. What i was looking not to accept the spammail and its subdomains

Comment: It identifies the spam mail. You can then decide what you want to do with it :)

Comment: @LalasM I've updated this answer to show how you can test an email address and receive true (valid) or false (not valid).